# is rich-snippet value type deprecated?

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, markup, rich-snippets

i´m using google rich-snippet markup

and you define the type like

```
<div id="ap_top" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
```

when you look up http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate in the browser, google say 404, not found thats all we know

i didn´t found anything about this is not used anymoren ?

anyone got information bout that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: okay google was doooooooown under, the link is back

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `data-vocabulary.org` URIs.

Even when they were offline forever, you could still use them. It’s about the URIs, not the pages you can find there.

However, on http://www.data-vocabulary.org/ you can read:

> Since June 2011, several major search engines have been collaborating on a new common data vocabulary called [schema.org](http://schema.org/).

So you might want to use http://schema.org/ in the future.